# What does + _ mean in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In python docs

```
>>> tax = 12.5 / 100
>>> price = 100.50
>>> price * tax
12.5625
>>> price + _
113.0625
>>> round(_, 2)
113.06
```

I don't understand what does this mean

```
>>> price + _
```

and how does it work

Comment: It means price plus the latest result

Comment: yes, duplicate of it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_` means the last result when you are working on python console

Comment: its work only console, or in scripst too?

Comment: Only for console. Doesn't work with scripts